# 2 Images On Top of Each Other - XML - Android

Tags: android, xml, image, android-studio

So I want to use 2 images. One should be on top of the other but smaller, so that the border of the image that's behind is only shown.
Take a look at these 2 photos.

Image that's behind (The border Image)
[IMG]http://i66.tinypic.com/25zgguh.jpg[/IMG]

Image that should be inside the border
[IMG]http://i67.tinypic.com/10mpgt4.jpg[/IMG]

XML CODE

```
<com.inthessaloniki.cityguide.view.SelectorRelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_poi_list_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/fragment_poi_list_recycler_item_size"
android:minHeight="@dimen/fragment_poi_list_recycler_item_size"
android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_clickable_item_bg_inverse">



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_poi_list_item_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fragment_poi_list_recycler_item_size"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fragment_poi_list_recycler_item_panel_height"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/global_spacing_xs"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/global_spacing_xxs"
    android:background="@color/fragment_poi_list_recycler_item_panel_bg">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_poi_list_item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.CityGuide.Body1.Inverse"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_poi_list_item_distance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_grid_distance"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/fragment_poi_list_recycler_item_icon_padding"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.CityGuide.Body1.Inverse"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I was thinking if I could add an    android:background="First Image" and make my Image view center but leaving some space on the edges for the background to be shown.

Would have posted 2 more images showing how the app is and how it should look, but the site won't let me post more than 2 links cause my reputation is lower than 10 -_-
Thanks in advance for the help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<com.inthessaloniki.cityguide.view.SelectorRelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_poi_list_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/fragment_poi_list_recycler_item_size"
android:minHeight="@dimen/fragment_poi_list_recycler_item_size"
android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_clickable_item_bg_inverse">


<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_image"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/foreground_image" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fragment_poi_list_recycler_item_panel_height"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/global_spacing_xs"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/global_spacing_xxs"
    android:background="@color/fragment_poi_list_recycler_item_panel_bg">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_poi_list_item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.CityGuide.Body1.Inverse"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_poi_list_item_distance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_grid_distance"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/fragment_poi_list_recycler_item_icon_padding"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.CityGuide.Body1.Inverse"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

hope I got it clear, you could simply use two layout and adjust margin for the small one.
put your images as RelativeLayout background or use ImageView in layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"></RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer was pretty much the same and solved the problem too!
I just had to give the answer to the one on that did earlier.

So thanks for taking the time to help me!!!